# Create Hierarchy in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a database table which represents accounts with a multi-level hierarchy. Each row has an "AccountKey" which represents the current account and possibly a "ParentKey" which represents the "AccountKey" of the parent.

My model class is "AccountInfo" which contains some information about the account itself, and a List of child accounts.

What's the simplest way to transform this flat database structure into a hierarchy? Can it be done directly in LINQ or do I need to loop through after the fact and build it manually?

**Model**

```
public class AccountInfo
{
    public int AccountKey { get; set; }
    public int? ParentKey { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }

    public List<AccountInfo> Children { get; set; } 
}
```

**LINQ**

```
var accounts =
    from a in context.Accounts
    select new AccountInfo
        {
            AccountKey = a.AccountKey,
            AccountName = a.AccountName,
            ParentKey = a.ParentKey                            
        };
```

Comment: So, what you have is an Adjacency List model in SQL (hierarchy maintained in a single table by way of a ParentId).  Are you wanting to transform this table to a different structure, or keep the existing structure (single table with a parentId)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure you currently have is actually a hierarchy (an adjacency list model).  The question is, do you want to keep this hierarchical model?  If you do, there's a Nuget package called MVCTreeView.  This package works directly with the table structure you describe - in it, you can create a Tree View for your UI, implement CRUD operations at each level, etc.  I had to do exactly this and I wrote an article on CodeProject that shows how to cascade delete down an adjacency list model table in SQL via C#.  If you need more specifics, leave a comment, and I'll edit this post.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/668199/How-to-Cascade-Delete-an-Adjace

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create an association property for the parent key:

```
public class AccountInfo {
    ... // stuff you already have
    public virtual AccountInfo Parent { get; set; }
}

// in the configuration (this is using Code-first configuration)
conf.HasOptional(a => a.Parent).WithMany(p => p.Children).HasForeignKey(a => a.ParentKey);
```

With this setup, you can traverse the hierarchy in either direction in queries or outside of queries via lazy-loading if you want lazy loading of the children, make sure to make the property virtual.

To select all children for a given parent, you might run the following query:

```
var children = context.Accounts
    .Where(a => a.AccountKey = someKey)
    .SelectMany(a => a.Children)
    .ToArray();
```